# How to add events/datasource to v-year-calendar with vue 2.5.2

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

Im using visual studio code with vue 2.5.2. I got a blank v-year-calendar. Now I want to add the datasource.
(https://github.com/year-calendar/v-year-calendar)

.

Since Im totally new to javascript programming, I have no Idea how tell vue 2.5.2,
that I need events/data-source. Im a (vue2) programming beginner.

```
<template>
 
  <Calendar language="de"></Calendar>
</template>
```

Now I want to add events:

```
<template>
 
  <Calendar language="de" :data-Source=[1,4]></Calendar>
</template>
```

Comment: The library documentation has [examples](https://year-calendar.github.io/v-year-calendar/examples) on using data-sources and events, but I would advise learning the basics of Vue before trying to use a third party library. The actual [Vue v2 documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/) is quite good. If you read the whole thing you should end up with a solid understanding of the framework. You should at least [do dilligent research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) before asking questions here.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem, so for anyone else interested, here is the code:

```
 <template>
  <Calendar render-style="background" :min-date="new Date()" :data-source="myDataSource" @click-day="handleClickDay"></Calendar>
</template>

<script>
import Calendar from 'v-year-calendar';

export default {
  components: {
    Calendar
  },
  methods: {
    handleClickDay(e) {
      alert('You clicked on ' + e.date.toDateString());
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      myDataSource: [
        {
          id: 0,
          name: 'Google I/O',
          location: 'San Francisco, CA',
          startDate: new Date(2023, 4, 28),
          endDate: new Date(2023, 4, 29)
        },
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'Microsoft Convergence',
          location: 'New Orleans, LA',
          startDate: new Date(2023, 2, 16),
          endDate: new Date(2023, 2, 19)
        }
      ]
    };
  }
};


</script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).